# RhinoMocks stubs with simplified implementation, Try-method pattern

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I want to mock a quite huge repository with RhinoMocks, mainly for the purpose of fully implementing a huge and frequently changing interface, just instead of using VisualStudio's "Implement Interface" default implementation (which requires all mocks to be updated for an interface change and causes a lot of junk code).

I currently use Stubs, but I haven't found out how to override mocked default methods, except defining every possible input value. This is especially bad when using the bool TryGet(key, out value) pattern and when I need a default behaviour besides, if the key is not found (here: return false/null, in other cases: throw exception).

Is there any way to implement method forwarding in RhinoMocks?

```
public interface IMyRepository
{
    // would normally be implemented by database access
    bool TryGetNameById(int id, out string name);

    // more...
}

// within some other class:

public void SetupMockRepository()
{
    IDictionary<int, string> namesByIds = new Dictionary<int, string>() 
    //create and fill with mock values

    var mockRep = new MockRepository()
    var repStub = mockRep.Stub<IMyRepository>() 

    // something like this, forward inner calls,
    // without defining expected input values
    var repStub.Stub(r => r.TryGetNameById(int id, out string name)
        .OutRef((id) => (namesByIds.TryGetValue(id, out name) ? name : null))
        .Return((id) => namesByIds.ContainsKey(id)));
}
```

EDIT:

I tried a delegate now, which looks better, but still has problems:

```
private delegate bool TryGet<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, out TValue value);

public void SetupMockRepository()
{
    // code from above omitted

    string outName;
    _stub.Stub(r=>r.TryGetNameById(0, out outName))
        .IgnoreArguments()
        .Do(new TryGet<int,string>(namesByIds.TryGetValue))
}
```

This is accepted, but when I run it, I get an InvalidOperationException:
"Previous method 'TryGetValue(123)' requires a return value or an exception to throw"

Comment: your `TryGetValue` method has return value. Add: `.Return(true/false)` after the `DO`

Comment: How can I get true/false from the delegate (depending on whether the ID was found) and use it as .Return() value?

Answer (score 0):

You can always make your own fake objects. With a mix of that and partial mocks, you should gain a maximum of flexibility.

```
public interface IMyRepository
{
    bool TryGetNameById(int id, out string name);
}

public class FakeRepository : IMyRepository
{
    // public on purpose, this is for testing after all
    public readonly Dictionary<int, string> nameByIds = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    // important to make all methods/properties virtual that are part of the interface implementation
    public virtual bool TryGetNameById(int id, out string name)
    {
        return this.nameByIds.TryGetValue(id, out name);
    }
}
```

Your setup would become this then:

```
public void Setup()
{
    var mock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<FakeRepository>();
    mock.nameByIds.Add(1, "test");
}
```

And if you need more sophisticated behavior, you can still stub method calls since all methods are `virtual`.

Comment: This would still require FakeRepository to implement the full IMyRepository interface (which is much bigger than in my example). I use RhinoMocks mainly to avoid this (and the need to re-adjust FakeRepository with every interface modification).

Comment: When you use a fake, you can define the default behavior in a single place instead of every test fixture for classes that depend on the interface. Yes, with every change of the interface, the fake has to be updated. The alternative seems to be to update all test setups which doesn't seem like an improvement. You are aware that the underlying issues are "huge interface" and "frequently changing", right? Maybe consider splitting the interface up if you have access to it, or use specialized adapters with minified subsets for the various clients.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first, partial solution:

The mock object required a .Replay() after the delegate settings, because the methods were used before MockRep.ReplayAll() was called (before the test itself).

I currently use expectations and record/replay logic only in few cases (and do not fully comprehend what it is like), and it is disturbing to find the mock objects fail on seemingly correct settings. I just want a default implementation with a few overridden methods/properties, which does not cause build failures if somebody changes unrelated parts of the interface.

Another, new problem is that setting up a .Do() delegate like

```
mockObj.Stub(o => o.DoSth(x))
    .IgnoreArguments()
    .Do(new Action(x => this.DoSth(x)))
```

causes an expectation error on a completely different method, which has default stub implementation and not been changed.

Comment: Mixing Triple A and Record/Replay is generally a bad idea. I would suggest against using Record/Replay anyway as it leads to brittle tests.

Comment: I would like to get rid of record/replay completely (except for a possible reset before 'act'), and I just now found it can probably be done by generating mocks from the MockRepository class (not instance). It should also do everything with infinite repeats by default (no error if a second call occurs). I found that RM v4 is supposed to be much simpler, but it seems like RM 3.5/3.6 can also do it.